# Table footer is not coming if table content extends to next page in PDF using xslt

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Table footer is not showing if table extends to next page.

**continue** text should come at the end of that table in first page. similar to table header which is coming properly.Whenever the table is extended to next page the "cont" should appear at the end of first page.

> Sample XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <DefaultView>
     <Department>2222</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2223</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2225</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView>
 </NewDataSet>
```

> Sample XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                              xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
                              xmlns:psmi="http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi"
                              xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
  <xsl:template match='NewDataSet'>
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:table>  
              <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
              <fo:table-header  keep-together="always">
                        <fo:block text-align="center" font-style="italic" margin="5pt" keep-together="always">
                            <xsl:text>Table</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                </fo:table-header>
        </fo:table>
          <fo:table-and-caption>  
            <fo:table rx:table-omit-initial-header="true">  
              <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
              <fo:table-header  keep-together="always">
                        <fo:block text-align="center" font-style="italic" margin="5pt" keep-together="always">
                            <xsl:text>Table (Cont.)</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                </fo:table-header>

              <fo:table-header >
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Dept</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell >
                  <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-header>
              <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <fo:table-body>
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Department"/>
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table>
          </fo:table-and-caption>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: There is no `fo:table-footer` in your sample XSLT. (Also, if you put the `fo:table-body` outside the `xsl:for-each`, you'll generate only one `fo:table-body`, and you really only need one.)

Comment: NOTE: Unlike omitting the start header for a table, there is no equivalent to omitting the last footer. If you idea is to have a footer that says "Table continued on next page" you can use markers and pull into the footer area and clear the marker at the end of the table.

Comment: Hi Kevin,Can you please provide some example to clear marker in table footer, so that it will be helpful for us to do the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look at the answer, I added comments for you. You can see right after the table it is as simple as setting the marker as an empty element. This would make it "blank". As such, it would pull nothing to the footer. You would repeat that surrounding your tables ... set the marker to the continued text, format the table, set the marker to nothing.

Comment: For below data also footer is coming at end of the page. footer should come only if table content extends to next page.If table content is not extended to next page then only table should come not footer content on that page. <NewDataSet>
    <DefaultView>
     <Department>2222</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2223</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
 </NewDataSet>

Comment: Then use <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="table" retrieve-position="last-ending-within-page"/> to only select the last one in the page

Answer (score 2):

Combining this with the other answer about table headers ([Table header is not getting repeated, if table content extended to next page in PDF using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255529/table-header-is-not-getting-repeated-if-table-content-extended-to-next-page-in)), here is a complete example showing both the table header and the footer being pulled as a marker into footer area when the table carries over.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
        xmlns:psmi="http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">


        <xsl:template match='NewDataSet'>
            <fo:root>
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
                        <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                        <fo:region-after extent="1in"/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
                       <!-- This retrieves the marker into the footer -->
                        <fo:block>
                           <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="table" retrieve-position="last-ending-within-page"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                       <!-- This sets the marker content for the footer -->
                        <fo:block>
                            <fo:marker marker-class-name="table">
                                Table continued on next page
                            </fo:marker>
                        </fo:block>
                            <fo:table-and-caption>
                                <fo:table rx:table-omit-initial-header="true">  
                                    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                                    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                                    <fo:table-header  keep-together="always">
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2"><fo:block text-align="center" font-style="italic" margin="5pt" keep-together="always">
                                                <xsl:text>Table (Cont.)</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Department</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell >
                                        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </fo:table-header>
                                    <fo:table-body>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Depaartment</fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell >
                                            <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:table-body>
                                </fo:table>
                            </fo:table-and-caption>
                        <!-- IMPORTANT -- This clears the marker so it does not appear on pages where the table ends -->
                        <fo:block keep-with-previous.within-page="always">
                            <fo:marker marker-class-name="table"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="DefaultView">
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Department"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

[image]

And if you had many pages is:

[image]

And if you have less than one page is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. Footer content is coming, If table content is not extended to next page. footer content should come only if particular table content extended to next page.

Comment: Where in the above image is footer  content on page 2? You likely did not clear the marker. Look at the very end of the table in the XSL and you will see the marker is set to no content.

Comment: I added a few comments in the XSL and made one change where it could be possible that you get a second page if the table is exactly one page long.

Comment: For below data also footer is coming at end of the page. footer should come only if table content extends to next page.If table content is not extended to next page then only table should come not footer content on that page. <NewDataSet> <DefaultView> <Department>2222</Department> <Title>Manish</Title> </DefaultView> <DefaultView> <Department>2223</Department> <Title>Santosh</Title> </DefaultView> </NewDataSet>

Comment: You should specify all the requirements then. The table can be less than one page, two pages, 10 pages? Then you surround with a block and use retrieve-marker-position with like last-ending-within-page.

Comment: I changed above XSL to add only retrieving the last marker in a page

Comment: That should solve issues if your table is less than one page or 2 pages or 10