# Table header is not getting repeated, if table content extended to next page in PDF using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Table header is not added to next page, if table content is extended to next page. Header is getting displayed for multiple tables, but if table content extends to next page then header is not coming and its staring the table row in next page. Need to append header before starting next page, if table content extends.
Sample XML:

```
 <NewDataSet>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2222</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2222</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2222</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2222</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2223</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2223</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView>
    <DefaultView>
     <Department>2223</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2223</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView>
    <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2224</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2225</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2225</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2225</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView>
    <DefaultView>
     <Department>2225</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2225</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView> <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2226</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView> <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView> <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView> <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView> <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Manish</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Santosh</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>Naveen</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>punith</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>bharath</Title>
   </DefaultView>
   <DefaultView>
     <Department>2227</Department>
     <Title>vijay</Title>
   </DefaultView>
 </NewDataSet>
```

Sample XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                              xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
                              xmlns:psmi="http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi"
                              xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">


  <xsl:template match='NewDataSet'>
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:for-each select="*">

                <xsl:variable name="tempdept">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Department" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="dept">
                            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::DefaultView[1]/Department" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$dept != $tempdept" >
                        <xsl:call-template name="header"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <fo:table-and-caption>
                <fo:table rx:table-omit-initial-header="true">  
                  <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                  <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                  <fo:table-header  keep-together="always">
                            <fo:block text-align="center" font-style="italic" margin="5pt" keep-together="always">
                                <xsl:text>Table (Cont.)</xsl:text>
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-header>
                  <fo:table-header >
                    <fo:table-row>
                      <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">Dept</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell >
                      <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                      </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                  </fo:table-header>
                    <fo:table-body>
                      <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                          <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Department"/>
                          </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                          <fo:block>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                          </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                      </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
              </fo:table-and-caption>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name='header'>
        <fo:table>  
              <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
              <fo:table-header  keep-together="always">
                        <fo:block text-align="center" font-style="italic" margin="5pt" keep-together="always">
                            <xsl:text>Table</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                </fo:table-header>
                 <fo:table-header >
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Dept</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell >
                  <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" align="left">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-header>
        </fo:table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample O/P Screenshot:
1. With multiple table:
[Table header with multiple table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7vDJ.jpg)
2. Header is not coming if table content extends to next page:
[Header is not coming if table content extends to next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdcJy.jpg)

Comment: As your template has a for-each for * on the template NewDataSet -- this is creating a single table with one row (and two headers which is also wrong). So one table for each DefaultView. I think you need to examine what you want -- likely creating one table with one row for-each DefaultView, not one table for each one. That is why you get no header (which is structured wrong also) because it never breaks inside a table, they are separate tables

Answer (score 1):

Just a total guess as you had many issues, but perhaps this is what you were trying to do. This XSL creates "rows" for each DefaultView and only one table with a repeating header with no table (cont) at the start only at the break.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions"
        xmlns:psmi="http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/resources/psmi"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">


        <xsl:template match='NewDataSet'>
            <fo:root>
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
                        <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                            <fo:table-and-caption>
                                <fo:table rx:table-omit-initial-header="true">  
                                    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                                    <fo:table-column column-width="25mm"/>
                                    <fo:table-header  keep-together="always">
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2"><fo:block text-align="center" font-style="italic" margin="5pt" keep-together="always">
                                                <xsl:text>Table (Cont.)</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Department</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell >
                                        <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </fo:table-header>
                                    <fo:table-body>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Depaartment</fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell >
                                            <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">Title</fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                    </fo:table-body>
                                </fo:table>
                            </fo:table-and-caption>

                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="DefaultView">
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Department"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border-color="black" border-style="solid" width = "85pt" border-width="0.4pt" padding="3pt" >
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is (in two page view):

[image]